# Url rewriting / redirecting

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

When I try to redirect an URL, I have a `"localhost//"` that suits before my new URL
I'm writing in the .htaccess like that :

```
"RewriteEngine On
 Redirect301 / www.site.com"
```

and the result in the navigator is : `"localhost//www.site.com"`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirectfrom your "old domain" or from localhost to the other site ?

if yes, then try to use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com
```

Comment: I want to redirect from my old domain. And doing so the "localhost" appears from nowhere on my url

Comment: And your second question ask as new, but yes as you thought you can do that with domain mapping like: www.domain1.com mapped to www.domain1.com/website2 also you can map subdomains.